# Ambiguous column name: DELETE in Sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

Here is my query.

```
DELETE 
FROM CategoryProduct_MM
WHERE PrdID IN 
(SELECT PrdID FROM CategoryProduct_MM t1
INNER JOIN db2.CategoryProduct_MM t2 
ON (t1.PrdID = t2.PrdID AND t1.CategoryID=t2.CategoryID));
```

Why i'm getting this error?

```
ambiguous column name: PrdID: DELETE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DELETE 
FROM CategoryProduct_MM
WHERE PrdID IN 
(SELECT t1.PrdID FROM CategoryProduct_MM t1
INNER JOIN db2.CategoryProduct_MM t2 
ON (t1.PrdID = t2.PrdID AND t1.CategoryID=t2.CategoryID));
```